# how to call "join()" method of one thread in another function in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I created two thread in main function.And I would like call "join()" method on one of thread in another.

How could I call ??

I am running "connect" and "sender" as  two threads.Now I would Like to call "join()" method on "connect" thread inside the  "void ClientSocket::sender()" method.

Is it possible to call??

these are code snippets that i ran as a two threads.

```
int  ClientSocket::Connect() 
{
    isConnected = connect(clientSock,      (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo,sizeof(serverInfo));

    return isConnected;
}

void ClientSocket::sender()
{

    if (isConnected == 0)
    {
send(clientSock, readBuffer.str().c_str(), strlen((char *)readBuffer.str().c_str()), 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously - you need to store the thread somewhere to be able to use it as object.

Answer (score 0):

Define the thread handlers outside of all the functions, i.e define them global. So they will be available anywhere and you can call the `join` method of both in all the other functions.

Comment: yes I created handler for a thread globally..and I assign  Connect() method to that handler..but I couldn't be able to create as a thread.                                                                                                          this is my thread handler  --> "thread connectThread;"   and I defined thread like this .."connectThread(&ClientSocket::Connect, &obj);

Answer (score 0):

This is a code example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

std::shared_ptr<std::thread> connect_thread, sender_thread;

class ClinetSocket {
public:
    int Connect() {
        return true;
    }

    void sender() {
        connect_thread->join();
    }
};


int main() {
    ClinetSocket socket;

    connect_thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>([&socket] () {
        socket.Connect();
    });
    sender_thread = std::make_shared<std::thread>([&socket] () {
        socket.sender();
    });

    sender_thread->join();
    return 0;
}
```

But I think the better solution is using some kind of events:

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

class ClinetSocket {
public:
    int Connect() {
        connected_promice.set_value();
        return true;
    }

    void sender() {
        auto connected_future = connected_promice.get_future();
        connected_future.wait();
    }

private:
    std::promise<void> connected_promice;
};


int main() {
    ClinetSocket socket;

    std::thread connect_thread([&socket] () {
        socket.Connect();
    });
    std::thread sender_thread([&socket] () {
        socket.sender();
    });

    connect_thread.join();
    sender_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Global variables are evil. They indicate that you have some problems with application architecture.